# login.microsoftonline is broken

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

i am using azure webapp with microsoft auth.
has been working fine for months.

however today it is broken.
the login.microsoftonline.com page is failing with css and js loading errors.

ie Request URL:https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.7415.7/content/cdnbundles/watsonsupport.min.js

is failing with a 
SSL_PROTOCOL _ERROR

i tried raising with azure support but i cant login into the azure portal as it also uses login.microsoft.com page.

anyone able to help?

-lp

Comment: I have a similar problem and have created a support case

Comment: Could you try to access from Internet. Is there any change of being blocked by firewall or Internet security antivirus?

Comment: this is not a network issue. this is across multiple devices on different networks.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to my version of this problem. I am in Australia, my ISP is Telstra and I have a NBN connection.  I do not have a proxy server.

I found changing the DNS servers from the Telstra default servers (61.9.194.49 & 61.9.195.193) to Google's DNS servers (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4) fixes the problem.  If the DNS servers are changed back, the problem reappears.  Changing the DNS back to Telstra reintroduces the problem.  Changing them back fixes the problem.  (You must flush the cache each change).

Hope this helps - but can only speculate as to why. Microsoft have accepted this as the solution to my problem and closed the support case.

The problem no longer exists when using the Telstra default DNS.

I suppose the take-home message is to remember your ISP sometimes caches stuff, mostly a good thing, but on the rare occasion causes problems.

Comment: Sound line the one I encountered in Singapore when my Azure resources were hosted in the data center which was being managed by the same Internet service provider.